# get xml attribute value of element based on another attribute using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Having some difficulty retrieving the value of an attribute.

Assuming xml that looks like:

```
<g id="formSide1Main" class="formSideMain">
     <g  fdtFieldName="Forename1"  fdtLorenzoField="lzoFnm">
     .....
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value of 'fdtFieldName' attribute.
Based on other similar questions, I've tried:

```
var svgDocument = XDocument.Parse(rpd.formmodeler);
var firstName = svgDocument.Elements("g")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("fdtLorenzoField") == "lzoFnm").FirstOrDefault();

 var attrVal = firstName?.Attribute("fdtFieldName").Value;
```

But firstName keeps coming up null. Any ideas?

Comment: In the Attribute, you don't need to get the Value property? x.Attribute("fdtLorenzoField").Value

Comment: Use Descendants("g") instead of Elements("g")

Comment: neither of those ideas work :(

Comment: SVG? You must use namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I achieved my goal with xml reader:

```
     string firstName; 
     XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(rpd.formmodeler));
     while (xmlReader.Read())
     {
      if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "g"))
         {
             var firstNameElement = xmlReader.GetAttribute("fdtLorenzoField");
                if (firstNameElement == "lzoFnm")
                     {
                       firstName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("fdtFieldName");
                     }
            }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is going to have poor performance with large xml documents, but I'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this i had tried i am able to get the value of fdtFieldName you have to use attribute for get the value of it. if you put debugger u will be having a clear idea of how to get each every value you want in xml

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("your xml");
string attr = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes["fdtFieldName"]?.InnerText;
```

or you can check like this it might little lengthy if your are good at ling just convert it

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(txtQuery.Text);
DisplayNodes(doc.DocumentElement);

 private static void DisplayNodes(XmlNode node)
 {
  //Print attributes of the node
  if (node.Attributes != null)
   {
     XmlAttributeCollection attrs = node.Attributes;
     string value = string.Empty;
     foreach (XmlAttribute attr in attrs)
     {
       if (attr.Name == "fdtLorenzoField")
           value = attrs["fdtFieldName"]?.InnerText;

       Console.WriteLine("Attribute Name: fdtFieldName, Attribute Value = " + value);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: this looks interesting as none of the other solutions work for me, but first I need to find the element that contains the attribute fdtLorenzoField="lzoFnm", and once I have that element then look for the value of 'fdtFieldName'.  How would I achieve this with xmlDocument?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It didn't quite do the job because that only gets me the root element, whereas I needed to query multiple  child elements ("g") for that attribute.  You got me on the right track though and I got a solution using xmlreader. thanks for your input.  I've posted my solution, so if you were to adapt your answer to work the same as my xmlreader solution, then I'll mark your's as correct as I prefer the idea of loading the document in 1 go rather than looping through elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
var firstName = svgDocument.Descendants("g").FirstOrDefault(x =>
 x.Attribute("fdtLorenzoField").Value == "lzoFnm");
```

or, alternatively, if you care about the nesting of nodes:

```
var firstName = svgDocument.Elements("g").FirstOrDefault()?.Elements("g").FirstOrDefault(x =>
 x.Attribute("fdtLorenzoField").Value == "lzoFnm");
```

Comment: I think my xml must be broken as this looks like it should work but it doesn't. I will test it with some very simplified xml.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your xml?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one
svgDocument.root.Elements()